# Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am getting below error for Deployment slots in Azure Portal. This message is displayed under Configuration.

*Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata*

This message is displayed for all web apps under configuration.

[image: schreenshot of configuration error]

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing this too on one of my deployment slots and am trying to figure out what's going on as well.

Comment: It looks like a bug. 1.Create a new slot, also get the error. 2. Even if enable the MSI of the slot, use [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#using-the-detector-for-app-service) to troubleshoot, it still tells me the MSI is not enabled.

Comment: Having the same issue. Will be reaching out to Azure support and let you guys know what I find out.

Comment: Also seeing the same issue since the last few days. Anyone heard back from azure support? @TodBirdsall ?

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace101, Per my answer below, I recommend reaching out to Azure Support. They did respond to me and let me know that the issue was on their end. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue. I reached out to Azure support and it turns out that this issue was on their end and affected many of their users. They have now resolved the issue and things appear to be back to normal.

If you are still seeing the same error message, I recommend reaching out to Azure Support.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was at Azure end and they made the fix and i no longer see this issue.